# Adding new commands to the syntax highlighting of a language mode

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I am working on a corporate installation. They have emacs, and it has tcl mode. The issue is that the command lassign is not highlighted, unlike, for example, set, or return.

What that I would like, is that w/o changing the original, installed, Tcl-Mode ELISP code, add lassign (and others) to the list/dict that are highlighted.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the function `font-lock-add-keywords`. It takes two arguments, the first is the major mode to extend. Alternatively, you can pass nil which mean the current buffer, which is useful if you call the function from a hook. The second is a list of *font-lock keywords*. This is a special data structure described in the documentation of the variable `font-lock-keywords`.

For example, it could look like:

```
(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
    '(("\\_<\\(k[A-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\)\\_>" (0 font-lock-constant-face)))))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-c-mode-hook)
```

The font-lock keyword match words like `kThisIsAConstant` using a regular expression (or regexp). The 0 mean that the entire match should be highlighted and `font-lock-constant-face` is used to highlight the match