# Adding new syntax highlighting for some major modes does not work

Tags: hooks, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

My question is similar to [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/adding-new-commands-to-the-syntax-highlighting-of-a-language-mode) and [that one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31475/how-to-change-syntax-highlighting-for-mode): I would like to add highlighting of some characters that are not highlighted in some programming modes, like `python-mode` and `fortran-mode`.

So, following **Lindydancer**'s answer to the first question cited above, I try the following in my init file:

```
(defun python-fortran-common-hook ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                '(;
                  ("+" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("-" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("*" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("/" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("=" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("<" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  (">" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  ("," (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  (";" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  (":" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
                  )))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'python-fortran-common-hook)
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook #'python-fortran-common-hook)
```

The problem is that for some reason this does not work (the characters I want to highlight still have the default highlighting), and my question is why.

**Note 1**: I tried the same with an `add-hook` form, and it works. But I would greatly appreciate to have the above form, not to have to write and `add-hook` for each mode that I want to have this highlighting. I am aware of `prog-mode`, but there are modes in it for which I don't want this highlighting.

**Note 2**: Of course, if there is a better way to achieve what I want, I would be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this, for me it works straight out of the box. Try to restart your Emacs, as it's easy to end up with intermediate versions of font-lock rules in hooks and other places when trying out new rules.

(Just one minor note. `*` has a special meaning in regexp:s so you should write `"\\*"` instead of `"*"`.)

If you don't want to write this for each mode, you can use something like (even though I don't think you gain much from it):

```
(dolist (hook '(python-mode-hook fortran-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook #'python-fortran-common-hook))
```

When it comes to if you can do this better, you could join all rules into one using the regexp `[...]` construct:

```
("[-+*/=<>,;:]" (0 font-lock-negation-char-face))
```

**Note**: If you want `-` to be interpreted literally when put inside square brackets `[` and `]`, you have to put it just after the openning bracket `[` or just before the closing one `]`, otherwise it is interpreted specially. Have a look also [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special) if you need `]`, `\` or `^` literally inside square brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the improvements you provide. I will just edit your answer about the `-` inside brackets (small detail). Concerning my code, I have just realized that it indeed works for `python-mode` and `fortran-mode`, but not for `lisp-mode` and `shell-script-mode`... Any idea why?

Comment: I found why it did not work for `shell-script-mode`: I had placed "`shell-script-mode-hook'", which does not exists. The correct hook is `sh-mode-hook` (`shell-script-mode` is an alias for `sh-mode`). It also worked for `lisp-mode`, I just did not notice at first that the lisp file I was testing it on was in `emacs-lisp-mode` and not in `lisp-mode`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for correcting the code I posted with regards to the minus sign, it's things like that that happens when posting untested code...